# System requirements for an exe created from py2exe

Tags: python, testing, py2exe, software-distribution

I have created an exe file from a python script using py2exe module. I have tested it across a no. of PCs with/without Python and it works well in all the cases. I need to write a 'Minimum System requirements' for this software before giving it to customers. How to do the same?
-TIA

Comment: Depends on your program: does it do lots of difficult computations? Then you'll need, for example, _Intel Core i5_. Does it involve GPU? If yes, you'll actually need a decent GPU. Does it require a ton of memory? If yes, you'll need a lot of RAM. Otherwise, no requirements at all, as Python can run on almost anything including Raspberry PI and fastest supercomputers.

Comment: From a software perspective, py2exe is mostly self contained. You'll want to check the minimum version of Windows your binary can run correctly on. You'll also want to point out that your binary probably won't run a system with a different instruction set. For example an x64 binary may not work on an ARM machine, such as a couple of the Windows Surfacebooks (Windows RT).